# How to Read XML node attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

Hi all below is my **XML** file.

```xml
<print>      
    <part keyName="logo" fontName="" fontSize="" fontColor="" bold="" italic="" underline="" maxWidth="45" textAlign="center" isBarcode="" isImage="true">
        <logo>testimg.jpg</logo>
    </part>      
    <part keyName="header" fontName="" fontSize="" fontColor="" bold="" italic="" underline="" maxWidth="45" textAlign="center" isBarcode="" isImage="">
        <SpaceSep>0</SpaceSep>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <text fontSize="20">Tax Invoice</text>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <text>Test Pvt Ltd</text>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <address/>
        <area/>
        <city/>
        <state/>
        <pin/>
        <country/>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <text>Phone: </text>
        <phone></phone>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <text>GSTIN: </text>
        <gstIn></gstIn>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    </part>
</print>
```

Above XML file contains parent root as **Print**, And child nodes as **part**.
I want to read child nodes and it's attributes in C#. If XML file contains **unique** node names then I can read them. But if all child's contains same node name then how can we read them.

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-attribute-value/ @Sagar refer this link

Comment: Using xml linq : List<XElement> parts = doc.Descendants("part").ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding well your question, you should do something like that:

```
//...
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
//...

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\directory\file.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> partElements = doc.Root.Elements("part");

foreach (XElement partElement in partElements)
{
    // read attribute value
    string keyName = partElement.Attribute("keyName")?.Value;

    //...

    // iterate through childnodes
    foreach (XElement partChildElement in partElement.Elements())
    {
        // check the name
        if (partChildElement.Name == "SpaceSep")
        {
            int value = (int)partChildElement; // casting from element to its [int] content

            // do stuff for <SpaceSep> element
        }
        else if (partChildElement.Name == "text")
        {
            string text = (string)partChildElement; // casting from element to its [string] content

            // do stuff for <text> element
        }

        // and so on for all possible node name
    }
}
```